# Need to return Boolean @ResponseBody. Now getting HTTP 406 error

Tags: hibernate, http, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am trying to return a boolean as a HTTP Response in a web application (REST, Spring, JPA Hibernate). Here's the code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/movieTheater", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public boolean getCustomerInput(Map<String, Double> input) {
    return transactionService.addTransaction(input);
}
```

Now, I guess this is not allowing me to return a boolean, but expecting something else. When I am trying to access in the browser the following:

```
http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm
```

I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 406 -

type Status report

message

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

Can you please tell me a way to send boolean as a response? If not, what else can I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

step 1: create an Enum

```
public enum ResponseStatus {
    SUCCESS("true"),
    FAILED("false");
    private final String status;

    private ResponseStatus(String status) {
       this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
       return status;
    }
}
```

step 2: create a class for returning the response details

```
public class ResponseText {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

step 3: modify the code as following

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/movieTheater", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseText getCustomerInput(Map<String, Double> input) {
    ResponseText result = new ResponseText();
    if(transactionService.addTransaction(input))
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
    else
        result.setMessage(ResponseStatus.FAILED.getStatus());
    return result;
}
```

now you can get output JSON like this

```
{[
    message:"true"
]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I tried the above steps, but I am still getting the same 406 error. What I did is, I added step1 and step2 to both the client code and the server code. So, now on client's side I have the code: ResponseText rresult = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8081/SpringMVCMerchant/movieTheater.htm", ResponseText.class, variable); But I am getting the 406 error and hence, rresult.getMessage() is coming as null. Can you please tell if I am missing anything here, or I misunderstood your steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue in produce JSON data, add the property produces like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/movieTheater", method=RequestMethod.GET,
            produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseText getCustomerInput(Map<String, Double> input) {
    //TODO:
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added 'produces', but it didn't solve the problem. In fact, when I am adding 'produces', the method on the server side is also not getting accessed, which was happening before. Any idea?

Comment: It should work. Otherwise there are some issue in your spring servlet.xml configuration, or spring webflow. please check the spring servlet.xml whether you have added the <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: Are you talking about applicationContext.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of spring to 3.1.3.release or higer.Then the @Responsebody will convert the boolean to JSON correctly.