# Spring MVC : Using model.addAttribute() in Controller to send various Lists to Ajax method

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I want to send different types of `java.util.List` to the AJAX method. I don't know if we can use `model.addAttribute` in the controller when giving data to AJAX method.

Situation is  :

```
@RequestMapping(value=/mappingurl)
public @ResponseBody void sendDataToAjax(){
    List<Item1> item1;
    List<Item2> item2;
    List<Item3> item3;

    model.addAttribute("item1collection",item1);
    model.addAttribute("item2collection",item2);
    model.addAttribute("item3collection",item3);    
}
```

Will this work when it is an AJAX method, if not, what can I do so I can send `List` of objects and access it inside AJAX method. I hope my question is clear, if not, please let me know, I will improvise. Thanks. :-)

Comment: What's you AJAX method on the client side consuming? You need to `return` (a JSON for instance) and should be able to parse/consume it in the client side when the AJAX call finalizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have any problem adding several attributes to your model. When you return to client side you will be able to get them in an AJAX request.

Problem here is **you can't use `java.util.List` objects by javascript at `client-side`**, so you must create `Json` objects or convert to `array` the `java.util.List`.

The only thing i would change in your code is to add a response to catch succes or fail of the method:

```
public @ResponseBody String sendDataToAjax(){
    // do your stuff and return "KO" if something goes wrong


    return "OK"; // if success
}
```

*This could be better done [by implementing an enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091091/need-to-return-boolean-responsebody-now-getting-http-406-error)... but this is a faster way*

After this, you can catch **inside the ajax request** the result of the `server-side` operatiion and continue in according to it.

Comment: So I can use the above code to send data to an Ajax method, correct? The next answer by @San Krish says no. Yes, I cannot access lists in Client-side, I guess only option is to convert to array or JsonList.

Comment: you can use to send various data objects, but no `List`, as @San correctly said...

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I will then use Array or JsonList. Just one thing, I know how to iterate through an array or convert list to array, but some other user in future might now, if you can write some pseudo code for future users.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO answer is no , you can't iterate or print the `Arraylist` inside the AJAX response.

You can instead convert it into `JSON-array` and iterate it in the ajax response. A nice startup example,

[Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array)